# How can I retrieve the injector for my application?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to run a function and have services injected into it. I thought this could easily be accomplished using `$injector`. So I tried the following (simplified example):

```
angular.injector().invoke( [ "$q", function( $q ) { $q.something(); } ] );
```

Which results in `Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $qProvider <- $q`.

I know I can solve that by using `angular.injector( ["ng"] )` instead, but there are actually several more dependencies.

It would be perfectly fine, if I could just retrieve the injector instance that is used everywhere else in my application.

The [documentation for `angular.injector`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector) suggests that you can retrieve it with `angular.element(document).injector()`, but that results in `undefined` for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't be needing this, but you can get your app's $injector using the root-element of your app (or any child element).
E.g., if you use `ngApp` on the body:

```
angular.element(document.body).injector();
```

Comment: As you said, I probably shouldn't be needing this. My approach to my problem was probably not right in the first place. However, your code worked and so did the example, I just used it at the wrong time in the setup process.

Answer (score 1):

ExpertSystem's answer worked perfectly for me

This works perfectly for me.  I'm trying to invoke a function from an angular service outside the angular scope in the document "resume" event for use in my cordova application.  Here is the code that I used

```
var injector = angular.element(document.body).injector(); //get the document
injector.invoke(['myService', function (myService) {
    myService.doSomething();
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $injector = angular.injector(['myApp','ng'])
```

For `$location` you need to bootstrap the app to the page (start the app):

```
var $injector = angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'])
```

This will return the injector every time you call it but won't create any conflicts if the script was already loaded.

Comment: That results in `Unknown provider: $rootElementProvider <- $rootElement <- $location`

Comment: That will result in "application is already bootstrapped". I don't think my approach to the problem I was having was right to begin with.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg it doesn't for me, but sure :)

Comment: Note that this approach willnot return the app's $injector, but a new instance. So you can't share data etc